# fedex integration for india not workin, "'The PurposeOfShipmentType is null, empty or invalid.',

Tags: magento-2.0.4

I have used the production keys for fed-ex integration, for India.

and getting the below error in the debug.log, can anyone tell me what can be done?

```
'result' => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'HighestSeverity' => 'ERROR',
     'Notifications' => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'Severity' => 'ERROR',
       'Source' => 'crs',
       'Code' => '691',
       'Message' => 'The PurposeOfShipmentType is null, empty or invalid.',
       'LocalizedMessage' => 'The PurposeOfShipmentType is null, empty or invalid.',
    )),
```

i read earlier that the purposeofshipmenttype is not there in magento2.0 and we need to enable it, can anyone please tell me how to do that.